# Error after upgrading WindowsAzure.ServiceBus Nuget to latest version - The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

We started seeing the following exception in our Perf environment after upgrading WindowsAzure.ServiceBus NuGet package from version 4.1.2 to 5.2.0.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

"{RequestInformation: { "HttpStatusCode": 408, "HttpStatusMessage": null, "ServiceRequestID": null, "ContentMd5": null, "Etag": null, "IngressBytes": 0, "EgressBytes": 0, "RequestDate": null, "TargetLocation": 0, "ExtendedErrorInformation": null, "IsRequestServerEncrypted": false, "Exception": { "IsRetryable": false }, "StartTime": "2019-08-22T07:55:37.2650437+00:00", "EndTime": "2019-08-22T07:57:37.276019+00:00" } RequestInformationSerializationErrors: [ "**Self referencing loop detected with type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.RequestResult**'. Path 'Exception'." ] Message: "**The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout**." Data: {} InnerException: { "ClassName": "System.TimeoutException", "Message": "The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.", "Data": null, "InnerException": null, "HelpURL": null, "StackTraceString": null, "RemoteStackTraceString": null, "RemoteStackIndex": 0, "ExceptionMethod": null, "HResult": -2146233083, "Source": null, "WatsonBuckets": null } TargetSite: { "Name": "MoveNext", "AssemblyName": "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventProcessorHost, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35", "ClassName": "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager+d__24", "Signature": "Void MoveNext()", "Signature2": "System.Void MoveNext()", "MemberType": 8, "GenericArguments": null } StackTrace: " at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BlobLeaseManager.d__25.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at telEventProcessor.d__14.MoveNext()" HelpLink: null Source: "Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventProcessorHost" HResult: -2146233088 } "

Comment: There are 10+ releases between `4.1.2` and `5.2.0` so you may be looking at quite a bit of change. Instead of jumping directly on to `5.2.0`, I suggest that you try upgrading in a progressive manner to each version and make the required changes as needed along the way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that.. as of now, we had reverted our changes.